# Adding labels to Key Value Pairs in JSON

Tags: python, django

I'm working with word counts and have the following in Django View (python 2):

```
frequency = {'This': 1, 'is': 2, 'a': 1, 'python': 5, 'dictionary': 1}
```

but need to render convert it so that the key and value pairs of labelled as below. The variable needs to be rendered safely into a Django template to be consumed as a javascript variable.

```
frequency = [{"key": "This", "value": 1}, {"key": "is", "value": 2},{"key": "a", "value": 1}, {"key": "python", "value": 5}, {"key": "dictionary", "value": 5}];
```

Given that my actual dictionary is much longer, I'm looking for the most efficient way of achieving this - could this be done in pure python before placing it in the context as string?

Comment: Try `new_frequency = [{"key": f, "value": k} for f,k in frequency.items()]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `items()` and list comprehension to do this:

```
frequency = {'This': 1, 'is': 2, 'a': 1, 'python': 5, 'dictionary': 1}
frequency2 = [{"key": i, "value": j} for i,j in frequency.items()]
```

Output:

```
>>> frequency2
[{'value': 1, 'key': 'This'}, {'value': 1, 'key': 'a'}, {'value': 2, 'key': 'is'}, {'value': 1, 'key': 'dictionary'}, {'value': 5, 'key': 'python'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it manually:

```
frequency2 = []
for each in frequency.items():
  frequency2.insert({"key":each[0],"value":each[1]})
```